# How can I convert JSON files to CSV files and then send them via STMP

Tags: json, csv

I need help creating a script to

- read JSON files named `settings_xx.js` (where xx is a two digit string)
- loop through objects with a "description" key
- parse the "description" key format `YYY-XXXXXXXX-xxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyyyyyy...` where

  - `YYY` is always three A-Z characters,
  - `XXXXXXXX` is a start date
  - `xxxxxxxx` is an end date and
  - the rest of the string `yyyyyyy...` is other variable-length information.
- create a CSV file with descriptions that are older then a specified date
- send the file via SMTP.

Example:

```
{"description":"TFW-20121203-20130803-1177SVR-Softerong-TO-VPN-FWR-0095-SVRCJO"}
```

So far I've been able to output the descriptions to a txt file in Putty with the following command:

```
cat settings_xx.js | \
sed -e 's/[{}]/''/g' | \
awk -v k="text" '{n=split($0,a,","); for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print a[i]}' | \
grep '"description":' | \
sed 's/:/ /1' | \
awk -F" " '{ print $2 >> file.txt }'
```

Comment: Great project! What is your question?

Comment: Point taken. I don't know where to start. Noob at this. Could this all be done in Powershell or should I look in some other scrip/language?

Comment: I don't know Powershell, but as it is just plain text formatting I bet you can.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

```
def d2u($d): $d | strptime("%Y%m%d") | mktime ;
def enddate: split("-")[2] ;

  .description
| select(d2u(enddate) < d2u($oldest))
```

If `filter.jq` contains this filter and `settings_00.js` contains objects with a "description" member such as

```
{ "description": "TFW-20121203-20130803-1177SVR-Softerong-TO-VPN-FWR-0095-SVRCJO" }
{ "description": "ZZZ-19700101-19710101-9999XXX-Abcdefghi-JK-LMN-OPQ-0000-RSUVWX" }
```

then

```
$ jq -M -r --arg oldest 20000101 -f filter.jq settings_00.js
```

will produce

```
ZZZ-19700101-19710101-9999XXX-Abcdefghi-JK-LMN-OPQ-0000-RSUVWX
```